# Why is my break statement not working in the if statement even though the print statement works?

Tags: python, break

I was writing a code to find the product of the first n prime numbers.

```
def num_primorial(n):
    print(str(n) + "---\n2")
    prime_count = 1
    product = 2
    i = 3
    while prime_count < n:
        is_prime = True
        for j in range(3, i, 2):
            if i % j == 0:
                print(str(i) + "****" + str(j))
                is_prime = False
                break
        if is_prime:
            print(i)
            product *= i
            prime_count += 1
            i+=2
    return product
    
print(num_primorial(5))
```

But, in the if statement:

```
if i % j == 0:
   print(str(i) + "****" + str(j))
   is_prime = False
   break
```

even though the print statement is working and is looping over, it doesn't break out of the for loop.

[Click to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qhwt.png)

Could someone please tell me what the issue is ?

Comment: What visible behavior have you observed that makes you think the `break` isn't breaking the `for` loop?

Comment: I ran the code and the print statement keeps looping over

Comment: Because you have `is_prime = False`, it doesn't implement the next if statement after breaking out of the for loop. Hence, it repeats the while loop over and over again. But I still feel like some logic doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Instead of trying to nest everything and write it all in one block, try to make functions that handle smaller parts of the problem. Once you understand how to use functions well, it will make it a lot easier to understand and debug your own programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exiting correctly ,

The for loop runs again because of the while loop

You should add another break after if condition to break out of that else it runs infinitely

When use break inside for loop , it exits only from for loop.  Youbhave an infinite while loop that never exits so you are getting in for loop again and again

In your example is_prime is always false so the count never changes

Comment: The issue was that 'i' never changes if is_prime is false. Putting the "i += 2" outside the last if statement fixed it.

Comment: @JACK still it fail if you pass 6 instead of 5

Comment: No, It works well for any number.Thanks your answer helped : ).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The issue was 'i' never changed. So it just looped over and over again because the the value of 'i' remained the same if is_prime was false. I just had to put the "i += 2" outside the last if statement inside the while loop.

```
def num_primorial(n):
prime_count = 1
product = 2
i = 3
while prime_count < n:
    is_prime = True
    for j in range(3, i, 2):
        if i % j == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break
    if is_prime:
        product *= i
        prime_count += 1
    i+=2
return product
```

Now it woks perfectly for every number.